# Does Oracle View calculate fields you are not trying to query?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, database-performance, query-performance

I am trying to optimize the performance of a query. The problem is:
Say we have view X. And it has attr A, B, C.
C is a calculated field.

Say I want to try to optimize by querying "Select A,B from X where A = 'some condition'" then if I need C I can calculate that later on with the much smaller subset of data to enhance performance.

My question is will this help? Or does an Oracle view calculate C anyways when I make the initial query, regardless of whether I am querying for that attr or not? Therefore to optimize I would have to remove these calculated from the view?

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **yes it helps** to select only the limited column list from a view - both in means of the CPU (value calculation) and storage.

In cases when it is possible Oracle optimizer completely *eliminates* the view definition and merges it in the underlining tables.

So the view columns *not referenced* in the query are not accessed at all.

Here a simple example

```
create table t as
select rownum a, rownum b, rownum c from dual 
connect by level = 10;

create or replace view v1 as
select  a,  b, c/0 c from t;
```

I'm simulation the *complex calculation* with a *zero divide* to see if the value is caclulated at all.

The best way to check is to run the query and to see the execution plan

```
select a, b from v1
where a = 1;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |    26 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     1 |    26 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("A"=1)
 
Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - "A"[NUMBER,22], "B"[NUMBER,22]
```

In the Project Information is visible, that only columns `A` and `B` are refrenced - so no calculation on the `C` column is done.

Even the other way around work; if you first materialize the view and afterward you make the row filtering. I'm simulating  it with the folowing query - not ethat teh `MATERALIZE` hint *materializes* all the view rows in a temporary table, that is used in the query.

```
with vv as (
select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ a,b from v1)
select a, b from vv
where a = 1;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                             |     1 |    26 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6605_5E8CE554 |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL       | T                           |     1 |    26 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   VIEW                     |                             |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL       | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6605_5E8CE554 |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   4 - filter("A"=1)
 
Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - "A"[NUMBER,22], "B"[NUMBER,22]
   2 - SYSDEF[4], SYSDEF[0], SYSDEF[1], SYSDEF[96], SYSDEF[0]
   3 - "A"[NUMBER,22], "B"[NUMBER,22]
   4 - "A"[NUMBER,22], "B"[NUMBER,22]
   5 - "C0"[NUMBER,22], "C1"[NUMBER,22]
```

Again you see in the Projection Information the column `C` is not referenced.

What doesn't work and you should avoid is to materialize the view with a `select * ..` - this of course fails.

```
with vv as (
select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ * from v1)
select a, b from vv
where a = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a *descriptive* language not a *procedural* language.  The database optimizer actually determines the execution.

For your scenario, there are two reasonable options for the optimizer:

1. Filter the rows and then calculate the value after filtering.
2. Calculate the value first and then filter.

Oracle has a good optimizer, so I would expect it to consider both possibilities.  It chooses the one that would have the best performance for your query.

If you still need `c` only for some of the rows returned, then delaying the computation might be worthwhile **if it is really really expensive**.  However, that would be an unusual optimization.